# php curl is not working in shopify api properly

Tags: php, api, curl, shopify, postman

PHP curl is not working in Shopify API properly. Sometimes it works and I get a response from Shopify but maximum times I get no response or 504 Gateway Timeout. But it works perfectly in the postman.

CURL Code:

```
$url = "https://refiral5-2.myshopify.com/admin/script_tags.json";
$shops_token = '64cbba144bc3cb166da91be13103f785';

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Shopify-Access-Token: $shops_token"));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Error log? php version?

Answer (score 0):

I got a 504 Gateway Timeout error when I tried posting a product with too many images. My theory is that Shopify has a time limit on processing API requests, so if your request takes Shopify a long time to handle then it will return this error.